# Bind textbox like dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

can i bind textbox like dropdownlist means in dropdownlist we can set datatextfield to show text and datavaluefield to insert value into database.

i have to do using textbox,I have add extender to textbox Autocompletetype then to show user i am fetching Student Names but on click of button i have to insert id of student into the database.How can i do any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ASP.net auto complete extender you can use a hidden field to save the value from the autocomplete extender eventargs and the textbox to display the value. You need to register a `OnClientItemSelected` callback attribute on the AutoCompleteExtender in your aspx page and then create a javascript function to set the value:

```
function SelectAutoCompleteValue(source, eventArgs) {
    var hiddenFieldID = source.get_element().id.replace('tb', 'hf');
    $get(hiddenFieldID).value = eventArgs.get_value();
}
```

Using this hidden field value you can save it to the database.

Comment: if you are not familiar with the autocomplete extender you can check this reference tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/345357/ASP-NET-Auto-Colplete-Extnder

Comment: and how i bind in databse text and id

Comment: On the postback you would read the value of the hidden field. That would be your data value for the item that was selected from the autocomplete extender. For example, the display value might be a string and the datavalue might be an int ID